# NPM giving little to no insight on how to resolve dependency issue

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm trying to add Typescript retroactively to a working project in Gatsby but NPM gives me this incredibly vague error:

```
npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
npm ERR! Override for @types/react@* conflicts with direct dependency

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/josephmasongsong/.npm/_logs/2022-11-28T22_21_01_949Z-debug-0.log
```

This is what the log says:

```
0 verbose cli /Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/bin/node /Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/bin/npm
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v16.14.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/josephmasongsong/Development/sandbox/josephmasongsong-v3/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/josephmasongsong/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 10ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 10ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
22 verbose title npm i @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom
23 verbose argv "i" "--save-dev" "@types/node" "@types/react" "@types/react-dom"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 6ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/josephmasongsong/.npm/_logs
28 verbose logfile /Users/josephmasongsong/.npm/_logs/2022-11-28T22_21_01_949Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 21ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
34 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
35 silly logfile done cleaning log files
36 timing idealTree:init Completed in 621ms
37 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
38 timing idealTree Completed in 624ms
39 timing command:i Completed in 630ms
40 verbose stack Error: Override for @types/react@* conflicts with direct dependency
40 verbose stack     at Node.assertRootOverrides (/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/node.js:1341:29)
40 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDeps] (/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:772:10)
40 verbose stack     at Arborist.buildIdealTree (/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:211:29)
40 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
40 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:153:5)
40 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:145:5)
40 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/Users/josephmasongsong/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:78:5)
41 verbose cwd /Users/josephmasongsong/Development/sandbox/josephmasongsong-v3
42 verbose Darwin 22.1.0
43 verbose node v16.14.1
44 verbose npm  v8.19.2
45 error code EOVERRIDE
46 error Override for @types/react@* conflicts with direct dependency
47 verbose exit 1
48 timing npm Completed in 707ms
49 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1669674062025
50 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1669674062030
51 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1669674062654
52 verbose code 1
53 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
53 error     /Users/josephmasongsong/.npm/_logs/2022-11-28T22_21_01_949Z-debug-0.log
```

I can't seem to deduce from the logs where the "conflict with direct dependency" is.

I've tried `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` flags when using `npm i` but neither is working.

Very simply, I am expecting my dependencies to install like normal.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would post your complete `package.json`.
There is absolutely no way we the readers can reproduce what you did
unless we get our hands on your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because I had forgotten that I had this `overrides` key in my `package.json`

```
"overrides": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
```